# reverse with accumulator in prolog - error

Tags: list, prolog

Could you help me solve some error ?  I don't understand this error.

```
reverse(L, R) :- reverse(L, [], R).
reverse([], R, R).
reverse([Head|Tail], Acc, R) :- NewAcc is [Head|Acc], reverse(Tail, NewAcc, R).
```

?- reverse[1,2,3], X).

```
Type error: `[]' expected, found `[2|1]' (a compound) ("x" must hold one character)
```

Comment: `is/2` is used to evaluate arithmetic expressions. `[Head|Acc]` is not an arithmetic expression. You can also do the unification of `NewAcc = [Head|Acc]` right in the recursive call to `reverse`: `reverse([Head|Tail], Acc, R) :- reverse(Tail, [Head|Acc], R).`.

Comment: *`is/2` is used to evaluate arithmetic expressions.* What does it mean exactly ?

Comment: It means that when you have `X is <something>` then `<something>` must be an arithmetic expression that can be evaluated, which also means all variables in `<something>` must be bound (have a value). You would use it, for example, like `X is (Y+7)/(2*log(Z))` and in that case `Y` and `Z` must have a value, and Prolog will evaluate the expression. If `X` also already has a value, then the expression will succeed if it's true and fail if it's false. Many beginning Prolog programmers mistakenly use `is/2` as a general assignment operator. Prolog has no "assignment" operators *per se*.

Comment: In contrast, if I said `X = (Y+7)/(2*log(Z))`, Prolog would *not* evaluate the expression on the right hand side of `=/2`. It would just keep it as a compound term, which internally looks like, `'/'('+'(Y, 7), '*'(2, log(Z)))`. See this previous question about [The difference between `=/2` and `is/2`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027449/what-is-the-difference-between-is-and)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your predicate works in principle but you probably want to use unification (=)/2 instead of arithmetic evaluation is/2 in your recursive goal:

```
reverse(L, R) :-
   reverse(L, [], R).

reverse([], R, R).
reverse([Head|Tail], Acc, R) :-
   NewAcc = [Head|Acc],             % <- here
   reverse(Tail, NewAcc, R).
```

With this small modification your predicate works:

```
   ?- reverse([1,2,3],R).
R = [3,2,1]
```

As pointed out by @lurker in the comments, you can express the recursive rule more compactly by incorporating `[Head|Acc]` into its recursive goal like so:

```
reverse([Head|Tail], Acc, R) :-
   reverse(Tail, [Head|Acc], R).
```

However, you might like to consider using DCGs for this task as they yield easier readable code:

```
reverse(L,R) :-
   phrase(invlist(L),R).

invlist([]) -->
   [].
invlist([H|T]) -->
   invlist(T),
   [H].
```

With the respective query:

```
   ?- reverse([1,2,3],R).
R = [3,2,1]
```

Comment: And you can get rid of `NewAcc = [Head|Acc]` altogether with `reverse(tail, [Head|Acc], R)`. :)

Comment: @lurker: I completely ignored that detail. Thanks for the hint, I incorporated it in my answer :-)